# Mock vs Import Then Mock

Tags: javascript, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to understand when I can just import a mock vs when I need to import the mock and still use `jest.mock` in the test file. I'm looking at the [manual-mocks example](https://github.com/facebook/jest/tree/master/examples/manual-mocks) from Jest's Github.

**One Step Module Mocking**

In the Lodash test, Lodash [is mocked](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/manual-mocks/__mocks__/lodash.js) in the `__mocks__` directory using `createMockFromModule`, exported, and simply [imported using the standard module import and used directly in the test](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/manual-mocks/__tests__/lodashMocking.test.js) (no additional mocking).

**Two Step Mocking**

In that same project, the [User model is exported](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/manual-mocks/models/user.js) and there is a [separate User mock file](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/manual-mocks/models/__mocks__/user.js). But in the [User mocked test](https://github.com/facebook/jest/blob/master/examples/manual-mocks/__tests__/userMocked.test.js), the User is imported but there is an additional step using `jest.mock('../models/user');`

**My Question/Confusion**

Why would the Lodash test not require the additional `jest.mock` in the test file, or why does the User test require it? In the project, it seems like I can test both *actual* and *mocked* User implementation, but Lodash will only use the *mocked* implementation, even though both are created/exported using `createMockFromModule` in the `__mocks__` directories.

Comment: Consider providing relevant snippets in the question, especially since they are small. The question should be fully intelligible without navigating to external resources that may become unavailable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The difference is that `lodash` is Node module and `user` is local module, the latter needs `jest.mock('../models/user')` in order for a mock from `__mocks__` to be used.

As [the documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) states,

> If the module you are mocking is a Node module (e.g.: `lodash`), the mock should be placed in the `__mocks__` directory adjacent to node_modules (unless you configured roots to point to a folder other than the project root) and will be automatically mocked. There's no need to explicitly call `jest.mock('module_name')`.

> Warning: If we want to mock Node's core modules (e.g.: `fs` or `path`), then explicitly calling e.g. `jest.mock('path')` is required, because core Node modules are not mocked by default.

This allows to avoid accidental collisions between mocks for NPM packages and local modules of the same name.

Comment: Gotcha. That makes sense. I appreciate it!